# ionic image upload failing due to npm or cordova

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Since a few weeks I got stuck on the Ionic file upload. I used the following tutorial: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/ . Everything looks good, up until the moment the user wants to upload the image. When clicking the Upload button, the server sends the "File upload failed" message back.
I created an entirely new project in which I also followed the tutorial and I got the file upload to work like a charm.
The frustrating part is I cannot seem to find what the cause of the problem is in my original project. I have compared NPM packages and Cordova plugins - thinking a version mismatch or something like that would be the problem - but without success.

My question: what could be the cause of this? Where should I look for the error when the code is exactly the same (copy-pasted from the tutorial), NPM is up to date and the necessary cordova plugins are installed. Is it possible that my original project has a package installed that does not work along with another package?

If relevant, the links to the [package.json of the original (non-working project)](https://pastebin.com/f8GKW71q) and the [package.json of the working project](https://pastebin.com/wM4pQq77).

```
{
  "name": "nonworkingapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/globalization": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.485.0",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.6",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ionic": "^5.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.24",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.10",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}

{
  "name": "workingproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I completely forgot and rather did not pay attention to because I was oblivious of its relevance is the **HttpInterceptor** I had installed into my project way earlier. Commenting its interference out made the file upload work like a charm... Wow.

I literally had code in there applying the application/json header to any call that did not have the Content type header. So yea... Problem found.

sorry